# Carrito de compras con variables de sesión PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un carro de comprar para mi página web, y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de hacer las variables de sesión, tengo definido un ciclo `for each` para que me imprima los productos, con un boton llamado **btnAction**.

El código del index.php es el siguiente:

```
<div class="appContentSection" style="min-height:100vh;">
<?php if($_POST){?>
<!-- Div de mensaje con respuesta al añadir producto + <a> para acceder a cesta -->
    <div class="cart-zone">
        <?php echo $message;?>
        <a href="cart" target="_self">Ver cesta</a>
    </div>
<?php }?>
    <div class="purcharse-zone" style="min-height:100%;">

        <?php 
        // Seleccion msql de todos los productos confirmados
        $sentence=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblpacks` WHERE CONF = 1");
        $sentence->execute();
        $productList=$sentence->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Ciclo para imprimir los productos
        foreach($productList as $product) {
        ?>

            <div class='product-row' id='fade' title='<?php echo $product['CONT'];?>'>
                <span class='row-price'><?php echo $product['PRICE'];?> €</span>
                <div class='vid-img'>
                    <img class='vid-img' src='data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($product['IMG']);?>'>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form action="" method="post">

                        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['ID'],COD,KEY);?>">
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['TITLE'],COD,KEY);?>">
                        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['PRICE'],COD,KEY);?>">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt(1,COD,KEY); ?>">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn buy-btn btn-orange-light" name="btnAccion" value="Add">Añadir a la cesta</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php  } ?>

    </div>
```

El código para añadir el producto a la cesta es el siguiente:

```
session_start();

$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['btnAccion'])){

switch($_POST['btnAccion']){

case 'Add':

// Comprobamos que todos los campos recibidos por post, sean correctos.
    if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY))){
        $ID = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY);
        $message.= "Ok ID correcto " . $ID;
        }else{$message.= "Upss.. ID incorrecto " . $ID; }
    if(is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['title'],COD,KEY))){
        $TITLE = openssl_decrypt($_POST['title'],COD,KEY);
        $message.= "Ok title correcto " . $TITLE;
        }else{$messag.= "Upss.. title incorrecto "; break;}
    if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['quantity'],COD,KEY))){
        $QUANTITY = openssl_decrypt($_POST['quantity'],COD,KEY);
        $message.= "Ok quantity correcto " . $QUANTITY;
        }else{$message.= "Upss.. quantity incorrecto "; break;}
    if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['price'],COD,KEY))){
        $PRICE = openssl_decrypt($_POST['price'],COD,KEY);
        $message.= "Ok price correcto " . $PRICE;
        }else{$message.= "Upss.. price incorrecto "; break;}

    // Añadimos el producto a la sesion 'CART'
    if(!isset($_SESSION['CART'])){

        $producto = array(
            'ID' => $ID,
            'TITLE' => $TITLE,
            'QUANTITY' => $QUANTITY,
            'PRICE' => $PRICE
        );
        $_SESSION['CART'][]=$producto;

    } else {
        $productNumber=count($_SESSION['CART']);
        $producto = array(
            'ID' => $ID,
            'TITLE' => $TITLE,
            'QUANTITY' => $QUANTITY,
            'PRICE' => $PRICE
        );
        $_SESSION['CART'][$productNumber]=$producto;

    }
// Imprimimos el array de la sesion
    $message = print_r( $_SESSION, true );

break;


}
```

Cuando añado un producto me devuelve el array con la información del producto añadido, pero a la hora de añadir otro producto, me sustituye el **array 0** en el que estaba almacenada la información del primer producto, por el nuevo producto añadido. Ayuda!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92345/discussion-on-question-by-noooma-carrito-de-compras-con-variables-de-sesion-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que he probado ha sido este:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['CART'])){ 
    $_SESSION['CART']=array(); 
} 
/*Añadimos el producto a la sesion 'CART'*/ 
$producto = array( 
                    'ID' => $ID, 
                    'TITLE' => $TITLE, 
                    'QUANTITY' => $QUANTITY, 
                    'PRICE' => $PRICE 
                  ); 
$_SESSION['CART'][]=$producto; 

/*Prueba*/
var_dump($_SESSION['CART']);

/*Imprimimos el array de la sesion*/ 
$message = print_r($_SESSION);
```

Te toca a ti incorporarlo a tu lógica para que quede sin error.

---

### Volver a lo sencillo

Si no funciona, puede que haya algo mal en todo el flujo de tu código. En ese caso, prueba en un archivo llano, sin ningún `if`, `switch` etc.

He probado esto y funciona:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['CART'])){
  $_SESSION['CART'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['CART'][]=array("id"=>1, "price"=>50);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Dado que quizá la sesión esté en memoria, prueba a limpiar la caché del navegador y a hacer un `session_destroy();` la primera vez. Si aún así no funciona, prueba con otra clave diferente de `CART` en la sesión. Y si sigue sin funcionar, entonces tendrás que revisar en la configuración de `php.ini`.

Cada vez que refresco la página, se agrega un producto a la variable de sesión:

```
array(1) {
  ["CART"]=>
  array(16) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
 ....
```

Comment: Nada, no me funciona a mi, he probado el primer codigo deltro del switch y me sustituye los datos, despues he probado el segundo código en un archivo llano y me devuelve lo siguiente `array(1) {
  ["CART"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
}

        array(1) {
  ["CART"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
}` y no se agregan más al refrescar. Y he limpiado el caché.

Comment: @Noooma Parece que ahora funciona. Prueba poniendo esto antes de iniciar la sesión: `$_SESSION=arrray();`

Comment: Intuyo que es asi `$_SESSION=array(); session_start(); `, haciendo eso, me devuelve lo siguiente `array(1) {
  ["CART"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["price"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
}`, pero refresco y no añade. Estoy empezando a pensar que tiene algo que ver con la configuración de mi `php.ini`

Comment: @Noooma debe ser algo de eso, en mi prueba funciona bien, agrega a `CART` un nuevo array cada vez que recargo la página (estoy probando en hosting compartido, en un dominio en línea).

Comment: Sabrias que parte de la configuración de `php.ini` tendria que cambiar?

Comment: @Noooma no sabría decirte exactamente. Antes de manipular `php.ini` puedes poner esto en un archivo cualquiera: `phpinfo();` , luego abrir ese archivo y buscar dentro de toda la información la palabra `session`, ahí te mandará a un apartado donde está toda la configuración actual para la sesión y revisa si hay algo raro ahí.

Comment: He estado mirando y no veo nada raro, lo unico `session.auto_start` esta en `Off` pero como no se si es normal o no prefiero proporcionarte la imagen con la informacion [aquí](https://gyazo.com/61c8050882c3e680b90d59bf24de3d12). Por otra parte `PHP Version 7.2.8`

Comment: @Noooma veo dos diferencias con respecto a mi configuración: En `session.cookie_domain` yo lo tengo vacío. En `session.save_path`, yo tengo ahí `/tmp`... Como ya dije, yo estoy en un dominio en línea no sé si tú estás en local o en línea. Tampoco sé si eso pueda afectar o no, pues no conozco mucho sobre las sesiones.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en local, pero probé el código en un dominio en línea y tampoco me funcionaba :/

Comment: Puedes quizá probar esto antes del `session_start`: **`ini_set('session.cookie_domain','');`** no sé realmente si la actual configuración sólo permite guardar cookies del dominio indicado en tu configuración actual.

Comment: Ostras! Acabo de resolverlo, soy un despistado... Añadí en el `.htaccess` una `cookie` que me establecia el dominio en linea en `session.cookie_domain`, ya que necesitaba pasar variables de sesión del dominio al subdominio, con lo cual en `localhost` tenia el mismo `.htaccess` que en el dominio y eso me estaba interfiriendo en las sesiones de el local host. Ya esta todo resuelto, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: @Noooma me alegro, a veces pasa eso, que uno deja un rastro por ahí que luego fastidia todo y pasan días sin que siquiera te imagines dónde está el problema. Saludos.